# how to use numpy vectorization for mutiple datasets, and then call a function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that contains name and date. And i need to compare them to others datasets that have name and date, and call another function if the name is in it, in the example i just mocked a return, that would be assigned to a new column in the dataframe. But i couldn't find how. Here's what i did so far:
*I need to use numpy vectorization

```
def getName(name, date, df1, df2):
    if name  == df1['NAME'].values:
       return name
    if name  == df2['NAME'].values:
       return 'HEY'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": ["JOE", "CHRIS", "AARON"],
    "DATE": [10, 20, 30]
})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": ["JOE", "JASON", "GUS"],
    "DATE": [10, 20, 30]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": ["STEPHEN", "CHRIS", "AARON"],
    "DATE": [10, 20, 30]
})

df['NAME_'] = getname(df['NAME'].values, df['DATE'].values, df1, df2)
```

The output should be:

```
df = 
NAME DATE NAME_
JOE   10   JOE
CHRIS 20   HEY
AARON 30   HEY
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you are using the "date" argument in your function, can you remove it to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 0):

So you are testing equality with the `==` operator, which will evaluate False because `name` is a `str` and `df1['NAME']` is a `Series`. I think you want to test if `name` is in a column. You can do this with a construct like `if name in df1['NAME'].values`.

But, even if you fix the function, you can't call `getName` just once and get the result you are looking for. Typically, you could use `apply` so the function is called for every row of `df`. You can do this with `df['NAME'].apply(getname, axis=1)`. But this isn't using  vectorization, as `apply` is a loop behind the scenes.

So perhaps you could use `join`

```
df1['NAME_'] = df1['NAME']
df2['NAME_'] = 'HEY'
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df3]).set_index('NAME')
df.join(df3['NAME_'], on='NAME', how='left')
```

Output

```
    NAME  DATE NAME_
0    JOE    10   JOE
1  CHRIS    20   HEY
2  AARON    30   HEY
```